# MySQL select latest combination from inner join

Tags: mysql

I've stuck on something for a while, I've searched a lot but I think I am not searching the right thing. Not sure if the title is appropriate but I've given my best shot.

**Schema**

- FormField: Think of this as the fields (meta data) in a form (Simple as id, label)
- FormData: Contains just the unique entry submitted in a form
- FormDataRevision: Contains the actual version of the unique entry (When entry/formData is updated, a new row is added here instead of changing the previous one)
- FormFieldData: The data submitted in individual fields w.r.t the revision.

**Scenario**

1. User enters a data; result: 1 formData, 1 formDataRevision
2. User enters another data; result: 2 formData, 2 formDataRevision
3. User updates the first one; result: 2 formData, 3 formDataRevision

**Problem**

I would like to get the last two formDataRevision entries as the first one is now obsolete.

Here is the code, it outputs all three formDataRevisions, whereas I just want the last two (latest revision for each data).

**Code**

```
SELECT fieldData.formFieldId, field.label, fieldData.data as data, data.id as formDataId, MAX(fieldData.formDataRevisionId) as formDataRevisionId
FROM DB.FormFieldData fieldData
    INNER JOIN FormDataRevisions revision ON fieldData.formDataRevisionId = revision.id
    INNER JOIN FormData data ON revision.formDataId = data.id
    INNER JOIN FormFields field ON fieldData.formFieldId = field.id
WHERE data.formId = 10 AND data.isDeleted = 0
    GROUP BY fieldData.id
    ORDER BY revision.createdAt DESC, field.id ASC
```

**Result**

The query returns this data [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzzYs.png), notice it repeats the formDataId:4 entries two times. First with revisionId:5 and then again with revisionId:29, it should only show the one with revisionId:29.

*Thanks* in advance.

PS: Also please advise if the entire query itself can be optimized.

Comment: Can you add the tables with some data here so that its easy to replicate.
On top of my head, you can rank the revisions ordered by revision id desc and pick the first rank to get the latest revision

Comment: Adding table screenshots
FormField: https://imgur.com/GwhNjnS

FormData: https://imgur.com/WHwrnD5

FormDataRevision: https://imgur.com/oqgJroi

FormFieldData: https://imgur.com/rfM8aXt

Answer (score 0):

Mixing `GROUP BY` and `JOIN` is problematic in multiple ways.

Keep in mind that a query like yours will

1. Perform all the JOINs and put the result in a temp table.  (The `WHERE` filtering happens at this step.)
2. Do the `GROUP BY`.  Typically this is "deflating" what was "inflated" by the previous step.  (Hence, a performance issue.)
3. Sort (to achieve the `ORDER BY`).  There may have been a second temp table built by step 2.  Or maybe the sort can be simply be done in RAM.

A common trick for improving performance is as follows.  And it *may* fix the problem of duplicates.

First, do the aggregates with as little effort as possible.  It seems that this archives that sub-goal:

```
SELECT id, MAX(formDataRevisionId) as formDataRevisionId
    FROM FormFieldData
    GROUP BY id
```

Then use that as a "derived table" and JOIN to the rest of the stuff, possibly even joining back to `FormFieldData` to get more columns.

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( the above query ) AS x
    JOIN DB.FormFieldData AS fieldData  ON fieldData.id = x.id
    JOIN ...
    ORDER BY ...
```

Note that I pulled the `GROUP BY` into the derived table; this is likely to be a performance boost.  (Especially if there had been a `LIMIT`.)

I see that there is likely to be a problem with my suggestion.  You are filtering on two columns in `FormData`.  If those are important in getting the correct MAX, then my code won't work.

Another issue...  Is this a "groupwise-max" problem?  That is, were you hoping to get the `formFieldId` and `data` that were associated with the `MAX(formDataRevisionId)`?  If so, then your formulation simply won't work.

So, maybe my formulation will work -- this is because of joining back to the same table.  First find the MAXs, then find the other two columns *associated* with each MAX.

For me to further wrap my head around your query, please explain the relationships between the tables.  In particular, specify "many-to-many" or "many-to-one" or "one-to-many".